# Convert Whitebox .dep to ArcMap DEM .tiff?

Tags: convert, dem, raster-conversion, filling, whitebox-gat

I am having difficulty converting my whitebox raster float file to an ArcGIS raster file in ArcMap 10.2.1

I followed the protocol outlined at: http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/ExportArcGrid.html

And although the conversion worked, the maximum elevation raster value decreased by 27m (max:690 to max:663m).

What could have caused this?

Is there any other way to convert whitebox float raster files to ArcGIS integer raster files?

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

That's very odd because in creating an ESRI floating point raster, Whitebox [simply changes the extension](https://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/browse/trunk/ImportExport/src/plugins/ExportArcGrid.java) of the .tas file (Whitebox) to .flt (ESRI). They share the same basic data format so there is no need to convert anything but the accompanying header file. Given this, I just don't see how the data could be changed in the process. Have you confirmed that the data has actually changed and that it's not just the value listing in the ASCII header file?

Another option for transferring data from Whitebox to ArcGIS is to use the [Export ArcGIS ASCII grid](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/ExportArcAsciiGrid.html) tool. I don't generally recommend this tool over the binary format, precisely because the conversion to ASCII and back again can result in changes to the data but it does generally work quite well. Alternatively, Whitebox can export to SAGA, GRASS, and IDRISI raster formats, which you can then convert to ESRI compatible formats using a 3rd party library like GDAL.